# remove certain records in logstash

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to remove image load urls from the logs when parsing them, but i've tried the below and it doesn't work:

```
if [message] !~ "*.(jpg|jpeg|gif)" {
  drop {}
}
```

So for example the below:

> [domain]/home/home.do
>
> [domain]/home/home2.do
>
> [domain]/home/image.jpg
>
> [domain]/home/test.do
>
> [domain]/home/image.gif

I want to be filtered down to:

> [domain]/home/home.do
>
> [domain]/home/home2.do
>
> [domain]/home/test.do

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct regular expression looks like this: (+ you need to use `=~` instead of `!~` since you want to drop images only if they match the regular expression)

```
if [message] =~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$" {
    drop {}
}
```

Comment: where do we add this? to the begining of the filter block or at the end ?

Comment: @petsoukos in the filter section

Comment: Yes, I got that. filter { inside here  }. But inside this block I also have other stuff, grok, mutate, date, geoip, etc. Should the if block be placed before those or after or in an else block ? Thanks for replying.